# VB.net HttpClient (.Net 4.8.1) and Cookies

Tags: vb.net, cookies, httpclient

I am replacing my old httpwebrequest with the newer 4.8.1 version of the HttpClient. Mainly so that Async can be in play.

I am not good at the syntax to establish cookies, and feel like I'm shooting in the dark.

Can someone help me with what statement to add?  Some of the sites I'm trying to read are requiring they be set.

```vb
Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
    'HEADERS & SETTINGS
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SEC-FETCH-DEST", "document")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SEC-FETCH-MODE", "navigate")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.somesite.com/")

    ' an attempt here
    'Dim cookies As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
    'Dim handler As HttpClientHandler = New HttpClientHandler()
    'handler.CookieContainer = cookies

    Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(page)
        Using content As HttpContent = response.Content
            ' Get contents of page as a String.
            result = Await content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103 -- Similar, VB.NET: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75394321/7444103 -- Use a `SocketsHttpHandler`, as shown in the first post, if your HttpClient object needs to *exist for a long time*. You need an implementation of, e.g.,  [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to handle different types of requests (different Headers / configurations) that are not compromised by DNS changes

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of cookies is allowing them to persist across multiple requests and sessions. That means you don't want to create a brand new cookie container on every request, as you might with the HttpClient. Rather, create one early and keep the reference around to use again and again, as you might with, say, a `Random` instance.